# use node js to do web crawler but can not search data

Tags: node.js

I use node js to do web crawler.
I want to show the weather,but always fail.

[image]

this is my code,please tell me what I wrong thanks.

```
const request = require('request')
const ironmans = [
  'https://www.cwb.gov.tw/V7/forecast/town368/towns/6400800.htm? 
   type=Weather&time=7Day',
]

async.map( ironmans, getInfo, (err, results)=>{
console.log(results);
})

function getInfo(url, callback){
request(url, function(err, res, body){
var $ = cheerio.load(body)
const result = []; 
const table_tr = $(".Forecast-box table tr");  
for (let i = 1; i <3; i++) { //  tr
  const table_td = table_tr.eq(i).find('td'); // (td)
  const time = table_td.eq(2).text(); // time
  const temperture = table_td.eq(4).text(); // temperture 
  const weather = table_td.eq(4).text(); // weather 
  result.push(Object.assign({  time, temperture, weather }));
  }
  console.log(result);
  })
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The weather table has been appended to the page by a xhr request, that mean if you use `request` to get the page resource, then you can not get the data table(like you `View page source`). Try another ways (headless browser), simple way crawl `https://www.cwb.gov.tw/V7/forecast/town368/3Hr/6400800.htm` instead of  `https://www.cwb.gov.tw/V7/forecast/town368/towns/6400800.htm? 
   type=Weather&time=7Day`

Comment: how I can know to use this website? where can I find?
 https://www.cwb.gov.tw/V7/forecast/town368/3Hr/6400800.htm

Comment: @samuraikyo37 Open developer tool (Chrome browser), in Network tab, when you click to `１週預報`,  `過去２４小時` or `逐３小時預報` button, a network request has been fired. This is what you want.

Comment: I am wondering that why  I cant get weather (which column have sun and moon picture), I try :              weather =table_tr.eq(3).text(); / or                                                    const a = $(".Forecast-box table tr td title");  weather = a.eq(1).text();    still not work. how I can do? thanks